# How can I prevent unwanted doctrine persists in symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4

At this point, I'm not sure if the problem is with doctrine or with symfony.

I have an entity called Field.  It has a property dataTable with the usual getter and setter methods.  In one of my supporting classes, I use the setter method to change dataTable to a temporary value.  I never call persist in this class or the controller that calls it.  However, I'm finding that the database is getting updated with this temporary value.

If need be, I can add a virtual property and use that instead, but I think the code would be cleaner if I can avoid that.  How can I ensure that doctrine only persists things I explicitly tell it to?

Entity Mapping:

```
type: entity

gedmo:
  soft_deleteable:
    field_name: deletedAt
    time_aware: false

id:
  id:
    type: integer
    generator:
      strategy: auto

fields:
  name:
    type: string
  sortorder:
    type: integer
  dataTable:
    type: string
  type:
    type: string
  columnAdded:
    type: boolean
  deletedAt:
    type: date
    nullable: true

manyToOne:
  section:
    targetEntity: Domain\Model\Section
    inversedBy: fields

oneToMany:
  fieldOptions:
    targetEntity: FieldOption
    mappedBy: field

oneToOne:
  zmrList:
    targetEntity: Domain\Model\ZmrList
```

Relevant controller code: (Persist is never called for anything in the controller)

```
 $columns = $this->queryBuilder->getListColumns($list);
 $filters = $this->queryBuilder->composeListFilters($list);
 $query = $this->queryBuilder->build($columns, $filters, $list->getForm()->getId(), $instanceId);
```

Relevant code in the QueryBuilder:

```
 foreach ($details['columns'] as $k=>$layerColumn) {
                        $this->columns[$layerColumn]->getField()->setDataTable('table_'.$alias);
}
```

Setter Function:

```
 /**
     * @param string $dataTable
     */
    public function setDataTable(string $dataTable): void
    {
        $this->dataTable = $dataTable;
    }
```

Comment: can you give the mapping code ? Controller and code that perform the modification of the related entity ?

Comment: what i am sure of is that the database get updated only if you use ** flush()** so debug your code and see if you are flushing the entity somewhere

Comment: `flush` writes changes done to *any* of the managed entities. "temporarily" changing a value of a managed entity is not clean, it's dirty. I really would use the temporary field or re-evaluate the approach.

Comment: @Jakumi, thank you. If you want to post this as the answer, I'll accept it

Comment: @AmyAnuszewski It's actually possible, I just added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*disclaimer: the following is true for the default change tracking policy (implicit)*

`flush` by definition writes any changes done to managed entities to the database.

Persisting an entity makes it managed und thus any changes to it, even if they are meant to be "temporary" will be persisted on `flush` (as A.Marwan already pointed out in a comment).

Since the semantics are very clear, I would advise not to set temporary values on fields that are managed (any mapped field that is). Either add a temporary property for that or re-evaluate the approach - maybe a service or a wrapper or whatever suits your use case better.

---

**comment to change tracking policy:**

Rikudou_Sennin's answer offers a technically correct solution to the technical problem, that entities get persisted, when the developer may not want them to ... by changing the change tracking policy. IMHO, that's semantically *evil*, ... well okay, let's call it problematic.

As a developer, I would always assume objects to have a consistent state - even if it's not yet flushed to the database. If it has a state different from its persisted version, I want to assume, that when the request is done, and **all or none** of the changed objects are written to the database, that the database is in a consistent state. "None" can be assumed given. "All" is hard enough to think about.

However, with a different change tracking policy and the implicit possibility, that a "dirty" never to be trusted object may swirl around, with values the developer can't rely on in any way, because it's unclear, if the object will be persisted or not, or maybe was persisted. That just adds more (unnecessary) doubts. It also is an additional source of hard-to-debug errors.

Summary of options:

- adding a temporary field (or additional var/object or whatever): reasonable effort and no impact on semantics (and assumptions)*
- changing tracking policy and mis-using a field: low first-use effort, unknown (possibly unfathomable) future effort(s), loss of semantics and assumptions (should require explicitly stated guarantees, and even then!).

*) assumes *somewhat* clean and properly structured code, with intact und uncompromised semantics.

Comment: Not true, you can change the tracking policy.

Comment: @Rikudou_Sennin okay, I stand corrected. However, I would argue that this is less intuitive and creates other problems and traps.

Comment: Do you mean changing the tracking policy or using the fields for temporary values? Changing the tracking policy to explicit is actually cool as Doctrine is much faster if you work with a lot of objects. I agree that using tracked fields for temporary values is not the cleanest solution there is.

Comment: @Rikudou_Sennin (explicit) tracking policy is less intuitive, because you have (duh) to explicitly keep track of changes. I won't doubt that it's faster. However (see edit of answer) I would prefer implicit over explicit, unless there are very good reasons not to. However, in those cases, raw sql might be even better ^^

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by changing the `Change Tracking Policy` from `Deferred Implicit` (which is the default) to `Deferred Explicit`. By changing it to explicit, only entities that you mark with `persist()` will be saved to database, even updates (in the `implicit` scheme all updates are tracked). It has other bonus in that it's much more memory friendly because it doesn't have to traverse every object that's in the doctrine storage, it traverses only those that you mark for saving with `persist()`.

Here's how to do that via yaml:

```
type: entity
changeTrackingPolicy: DEFERRED_EXPLICIT # can be DEFERRED_IMPLICIT, DEFERRED_EXPLICIT or NOTIFY

# the rest of your config
```

Comment: I think your answer was what I was originally looking for - however, I think Jakumi was correct in that I shouldn't be doing what I was doing.  I created a virtual property instead of making temporary changes to the original field.